# how to display imageview tilted?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, transformation

i want to show my `image view` some `arbitrary degrees tilted` instead of `just simple straight` how to transform it to show tilted?
Please help me.

**Edit**

this is the image view at present
[image]

and i want like this
[image: only image frame with white border will be tilted or slanted]

**only white bordered image view i want to tilt(slanted) not tiled**

Comment: take a look at the apple demo code: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoScroller/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: i don't want to tiled the imageview but want to make it slanted for some degrees

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just set the `imageView`s `transform` property:

```
// 10 degrees
imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / 180 * 10);
```

Comment: it is transformed to the given degree but the frame's size is get changed

Comment: The `frame` does, since it is the smallest non-rotated-rectangle containing the view. The `bounds`, however, should stay the same. Check [this guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaViewsGuide/Coordinates/Coordinates.html) out.