# Can I programmatically flip the entire display contect such that it is upside down

Tags: ios

I have a teaching app on an iPad where the iPad is fixed to the table.
Teacher on one side and student on the other. I would like the teacher to
make setup operations he/she can read normally and then have the entire
display flip such that the student can read as normal.

Answer (score 1):

yes this is possible to get that type of flip for that you have to use `UIGestureRecognizer`on swapping the view can be flipped upside down and vice a versa for more information read this articles
[http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Identifying_iPhone_Gestures_using_iOS_4_Gesture_Recognizers_(Xcode_4)](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Identifying_iPhone_Gestures_using_iOS_4_Gesture_Recognizers_%28Xcode_4%29)

http://mobiledevelopertips.com/event-handling/gestures-recognizers-tap-pinchzoom-rotate-swipe-pan-long-press.html

http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/10/14/working-with-uigesturerecognizers/

Enjoy this may help you allot 
happy codding
:)

**EDIT**
You can refer my question and the answer of this can help you allot see the accepted answer question is [how to display imageview tilted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10394376/how-to-display-imageview-tilted)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is possible. 
You can use CABasicAnimation for this-

```
CABasicAnimation* rotationAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
rotationAnimation.toValue = // To extent that you want.
```

There are couple of other ways to achieve this.